# Regular expression to get string between tags with or without id attribute

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a string like below. **I want to write a preg_match_all() function to get '*one*' and '*two*'**. What change have to be done to the expression below to get the desired result?

```
$featureTab = "<li>one</li><li id='someId'>two</li>";
```

I have tried below code.

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=\<li\>)(.*?)(?=\<\/li\>)/', $featureTab ,$matches);
```

But it just returns '**one**'. as the pregx only considers strings between the **li** tag not with **id**. Help me with a regular expression that will return both **one** and **two**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use below regex

```
<li.*?>(.*?)<\/li>
```

Over here

```
`<li.*?>` here `(.*)` is to capture all attributes of `li` and `?` is to if no attributes is defined or not even space count also
```

As both has different `li` structure

You can check it

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/YSgKVm/1)

> Note: For `HTML/XML` parsing don't go for regex you can simply use `DOMDocument` for same

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
<li[^>]*>(.*?)<\/li>
```

---

```
$re = '/<li[^>]*>(.*?)<\/li>/';
$str = '<li>one</li><li id=\'someId\'>two</li>';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Check out the result here: https://3v4l.org/arFRq

Comment: This works for that particular string. Can you please help me with a expression to match text between any number of li tags (with or without id)